# Add auto slashes to date field extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, dom-events, datetime-format

I am using a date field in extjs and I want it such that whenever a user adds a **date manually via keyboard(not by selecting date from date picker)** then slashes should be added automatically to that date entered by user.

For example:
If date entered is 2122013 then it should be formatted to 2/12/2013 and so on.

I have a pure JavaScript solution in place for a simple text field in a form which is given below and it works well adding slashes to text field, what I want to know is that is this automatic adding of slashes is possible by using any config options provided by EXTJS date-field or Ext.date rather than using a pure JavaScript solution.

JAVASCRIPT CODE THAT WORKS CURRENTLY:

```
function FixShortDate(txtBox) {
  if (txtBox == null) {
    return ''
  }

  var re = new RegExp(/(\d{6})(\d{2})?/);

  if (re.test(txtBox.value)) {
    if (txtBox.value.length == 8) {
      txtBox.value = txtBox.value.substring(0, 2) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(2, 4) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(4, 8)
    }
    if (txtBox.value.length == 7) {
      txtBox.value = txtBox.value.substring(0, 2) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(2, 3) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(3, 8)
    }

    if (txtBox.value.length == 6) {
      if (txtBox.value.substring(4, 6) < 20) {
        txtBox.value = txtBox.value.substring(0, 2) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(2, 4) + '/20' + txtBox.value.substring(4, 6);
      } else {
        txtBox.value = txtBox.value.substring(0, 2) + '/' + txtBox.value.substring(2, 4) + '/19' + txtBox.value.substring(4, 6);
      }
    }
  }
  return txtBox.value;
}
```

Also I would like to know if this is possible at the same moment when is user is entering the dates (i.e. by capturing any keyboard events.)

Comment: If you exit the field ExtJs formats the date for you.

Comment: i checked that and it will work only when you enter 8 digits in any particular format. In my case it is possible that a user will enter date which will be less than 8 digits such as 2 2 2013...it wont work then.

Comment: But If you trying to make your requirement you don't know if a user enters `22` or means 2nd of February.

Comment: so you are suggesting that 8 digits should be required compulsorily or is there any other way out..?

Comment: I asked the testers at my work and they say it's not compulsorily. So we need the other way I guess :) Did you take a look @ the [altFormats](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-altFormats) config?

Comment: i had looked at it just once in the docs but haven't tried it yet as it didn't have d - m - y format to check...will check it out in code.

Answer (score 0):

> is possible by using any config options provided by EXTJS date-field or Ext.date rather than using a pure JavaScript solution.

No

> Also I would like to know if this is possible at the same moment when is user is entering the dates (ie. by capturing any key board events.)

No